# Can I use Oracle's JDBC driver in an MIT licenced project?

Tags: licensing, derivative-works, mit

I have decided to make a project of mine free and open source under the MIT licence. This project uses Oracle's JDBC driver. My question is am I able to include ojdbc in my Github project and if so, how do I handle licencing?

[Here is](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/distribution-license-152002.html) the official licence document, but even after reading it I am still not sure whether I can include it in my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JDBC drivers from Oracle are using a proprietary license and I would avoid redistributing any of their binaries on principle.

Beside its proprietary nature one of the most onerous terms is this IMHO:

> Prior to distributing the programs you shall require your end users to execute an agreement binding them to terms consistent with those contained in this section and the sections of this agreement entitled  ....

This is practically impossible to enforce for FLOSS... Say you put your project on Github in a public repo: how would you be able to enforce the execution of a *binding agreement*?

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: a comment explaining why would be nice

Answer (score 3):

As an update valid for newer version of Oracle JDBC drivers, Oracle states the following in its FAQ https://www.oracle.com/it/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html

> Can third party vendors distribute Oracle's JDBC drivers along with their own software?
>
> If you are a third party software company (and Oracle partner) then please check out [FUTC](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/licenses/oracle-free-license.html) license and run this by your legal department and then contact your local Oracle sales rep for more details.

FUTC license should allow redistribution, but considering how shady the FAQ is, I wouldn't do it unless you are an Oracle partner with a legal department. I think it's safe to have it as a source code dependency of your project, the tricky part would be distributing it as part of a binary release of your software.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Philippe. However you should note, that newer OJDBC drivers (since 19.6) are under FUTC license according to:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-19-7-c-downloads.html

This is a non-clickthrough license. Therefore the artefacts are also available in public repositories (in contrast to the removed older versions). E.g.

https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc8/19.7.0.0/jar